# How can I display a website in Python aplication

Tags: javascript, python, web, browser

There

I am writing a Python application on win7. I would like to display/access a website in one  window/panel of the app. Just like there is a browser window in my main app window. For a static http web page it should not be a problem. However, the website I need access/display includes javascript or something else (flash?). Is there any solution to embed a full functional web browser into a Python application window? Thank you.

Lanny

Comment: What GUI toolkit/api are you using? And of course, what have you tried?

Comment: At the moment I am just using wxPython, trying to write a desktop application on Win7. I have tried webbrowser and wx.html. They can only display a static http page on one of wx.panels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeap!

Just look for PyQt and QWebKit.

Doc:
http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qtwebkit.html

Comment: Hi, Many thanks for the info. Is there any sample I can find for this purpose?